# Trying to redirect to a script using htaccess - not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to use the RewriteRule instead of a basic redirect to achieve the following 3 minor goals.

1) Redirect www.example.com to:

http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/b/c/d/myScript.pl

So when a visitor comes to example.com, the Perl script "myScript.pl" serves the page.  Everything works fine with the fully qualified path.  I just need to automatically redirect it in htaccess.  I'm using a redirect in index.html right now, but I prefer to use htaccess.

2) Remove the subfolders "cgi-bin/b/c/d" from view.

3) Remove the ".pl" suffix from the script

I just cannot seem to get the syntax correct in htaccess to achieve these items.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Rule,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^myScript$ cgi-bin/b/c/d/myScript.pl [L]
```

Comment: That worked as far as redirecting, thank you!  Is there a way to hide cgi-bin/b/c/d and only show www.example.com/myScript.pl?

Comment: you can directly use `www.example.com/myScript` the rest of directory path will not show.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work, actually.  I thought I tested it correctly.  I get the following error:   Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.